# Inno Setup Error "Text is not inside a section." after upgrade

Tags: inno-setup

I recently upgraded my Inno Setup from version 5.4.3(u) to version 5.5.5(a), and now I'm getting an error for a script which used to compile fine with the previous version.

This is Inno Setup's output:

```
[ISPP] Preprocessing.
[ISPP] Preprocessed.

Error on line 1 in c:\Workspace\MyProject\MyInstaller.iss: Text is not inside a section.
```

The line in question is:

```
#if MYLANG == MYLANG_ENGLISH
```

So the processor is running, but somehow this line is not preprocessed. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce (with clean ANSI Inno Setup 5.5.5 installation; haven't tested upgrade from 5.4.3 though). My guses is that the problem lies just in that upgrade.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure myself why the bug happened on that particular line, but it definitely worked with 5.4.3(u) and 5.5.5(u), but not with 5.5.5(a). I tested that. But my script file is rather complex and has some Unicode strings in it (localization), so it probably won't be reproducible with a simple script.

Comment: I can imagine that the upgrade you installed have not upgraded preprocessor itself and you ended up with ANSI Inno Setup and Unicode preprocessor. But it's just a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was that I had upgraded from a Unicode version to an ASCII version. After re-installing, this time with 5.5.5 (u), I don't get any errors anymore.

Comment: That's it.  That's the answer.  Don't install the non-unicode version in the first place.